# How to plot every image in portrait mode

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot my images in portrait mode. But, the result is in landscape mode. I have searched this in the Internet with no luck.

This is my code (python3):

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4, 7))
columns = 2
rows = 4
for i in range(1, columns*rows +1):
    datagen=keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
    test_gen = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=df_test,
        directory=test_path,
        x_col=df_test.columns[3],
        y_col=df_test.columns[0],
        batch_size=1,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode="categorical",
        target_size=(64,128))

    " Generate one image and y label"
    X, y = test_gen.next()

    img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(X[0])
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.imshow(img)
    img_vector = loaded_model.predict(X)

    label = classify_image(img_vector, strPathFeat)
    _y = np.argmax(y)
    plt.title("{}/{}".format(_y,label))
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

And this is the result:

[image: Images are taken from Market 1501 dataset. Every image has 64x128 in dimension.]

Images are taken from Market 1501 dataset. Every image has 64x128 in dimension.

NOTE: I am not asking about how to plot images in paper's portrait mode, but rather image in my plot. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if someone can provide me how to "beautify" the appearance (eg. minimize blank space, etc) to be included in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, just add this code:

```
img = img.resize((68, 128))
```

after `img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(X[0])` resolve my problem.